# facebook FB.ui feed dialog not working in Explorer and Safari

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, safari, feed, fb.ui

I am having issues with publishing feeds to facebook. Following code works fine in Mozilla and Google Chrome but popup window will not appear in Explorer and Safari. DO you have and idea why is this happening? Thanks for your thoughts.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Website</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>

  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
  </script>


  <script>
     FB.init(
{ 
        appId:'3716911111111111',
    cookie:true, 
        status:true, 
    xfbml:true
    });



     FB.ui({ method: 'feed',
    display:'touch',
    picture: 'http://nerdyparrot.com/pics/Spanish1.jpg',
    link: 'http://nerdyparrot.com/',
        name: 'Nerdy Parrot',   
    caption: 'Learn languages online',
        description: 'Nerdy Parrot offers interactive way of learning foreign languages online.',
    redirect_uri: 'http://nerdyparrot.com'
});

  </script>



 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by replacing `redirect_uri: 'http://
nerdyparrot.com'` by `redirect_uri: 'http://
nerdyparrot.com',`(extra comma at the end).

Comment: Hi Ashutosh,thank you for your reply. I had a go and played with commas a bit but whatever I did, the result was always the same: Mozilla and Chrome perfect but Safari and Explorer are white... Thanks anyway. It is driving me mad now.